# where to store build artefacts: Grunt, node.js backend, github, android, iOS client

Tags: android, node.js, github, gradle, gruntjs

We are struggling to come up with a good idea of how to integrate our build environments, now that we start using swagger-..codegen to generate API classes from our backend api for the android app, iOS app and the webclient.

**Current situation:**

- we use several (private) github repositories

  - node.js backend: grunt build with tests and CI using cloudbased CI service- running codeGen for web- and android clients api access classes on sucessful builds, continous deployment to heroku test environement,
  - web Frontend, grunt build with tests and CI using cloudbased CI service and and continous deployment to herku test env.
  - android app, using gradle build and same CI, no continous deployment so far.
  - and soon there will be an iOS app as well...

This is private, non-OSS-code.

**The requirement:**
The different clients should be able to specify a dependency to the generated backend access libraries and get them during the build. The clients should be able to get the "latest" version or a specified fixed version, like with npm semantic dependencies. I could certainly enhance our build to upload the build artefacts to somewhere on successful CI builds, but the question is where to... what is the easiest way to set this up.

- do we need one, (or even several) private artefact repositories (nexus, npm, bower, ...)
- should we (ab)use github repositories to store the built artefacts in?
- we could also publish the build artefacts to S3 or something similar...

any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only things you should really store are your separate "tasks" folders if you are doing some custom tasks, your grunt.js (.coffee), resources (that you may use for pre-build tasks -less,coffee/views, coffee/models all your custom stuff), and your package.json. That way any new developer just grabs those form source, and then runs npm install to pull all your dependencies from your package.json.
/resources
grunt.coffee
package.json

I then have some tasks that pull and run bower tasks (pull latest jqm, set that up, pull various libraries.)

As far as node_modules I wouldn't store those anywhere. This is a simple script / app I wrote that works almost end to end with compiling a JQM app, calling phonegap scripts, building the app and ultimately ending up with an xcode app package.

Maybe this will give you some ideas. So far I have found it best to do the above.

https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqm

Comment: thanks for our answer. this would obviously work, but in our current situation it is not possible. The clients are developed by external partners who have no access to the backend sources/repository, therefore I would like to generate the libs as part of the backend build and store them, so that the client builds can pull them in as dependency.

Comment: I think you would best off then adding everything to artifact, or a repository svn, git system. There will be a lot of change though on the node packages.